# Why do I keep getting the error "min() arg is an empty sequence"?

Tags: python, max, min

I have the following code:

```
test_file = open("test.txt","r")
numbers = test_file.readlines()
numbers = map(int,numbers)
print("Maximum number in list:", max(numbers))
print("Minimum number in list:", min(numbers))
test_file.close()
```

Can you help me please because I keep getting the error message: min() arg is an empty sequence. (I have the numbers 15, 30, 4, 9, 41, 76, 32 written into the file, and they are in different lines).

I get this output:

```
Maximum number in list: 76
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\student-server\users$\16fvarela\Documents\YEAR 
9\CS\Notes\PYTHON\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print("Minimum number in list:", min(numbers))
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `numbers`

```
numbers = map(int,numbers)
```

is an iterator (in python 3 that is; in python 2 you would have gotten a list and everything would have worked as expected); when you apply `max(numbers)` you exhaust the iterator; `min` has nothing to iterate over any more (i.e. `min` will complain about an empty sequence).

if your list of numbers is short enough you could fix that by

```
numbers = tuple(map(int,numbers))
```

Comment: You should add that in Python 2 the `map` function returns a list. it was changed in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert map to list:

```
numbers = list(map(int,numbers))
```